# How can I bind a mahapps method to a button property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm still working to learn WPF and XAML, along with MvvM and Prism.

I'm using MahApps along with Prism, and have an icon embedded into a button. I want to call the "Spin" method on this icon whenever the mouse hovers over the icon.

How can I do this?

Below is the code:

```
<Grid Background="#52514e">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical">

        <CheckBox Content="CanExecute" IsChecked="{Binding CanExecute}"></CheckBox>
        <Button  x:Name="TestButton" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"  Background="#52514e" Height="35" Width="35" BorderThickness="0" ToolTip=" Marks the current work order as complete.">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                            
                        </Trigger>
                        
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <iconPacks:Unicons Width="35" Height="35" Kind="Cog" Spin="True"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iconPacks:Unicons` element is a markup extension and not a control. Use the `PackIconUnicons` control instead and bind the `Spin` property to the `IsMouseOver` property of the parent button.

```
<iconPacks:PackIconUnicons Width="35" Height="35" Kind="Cog" Spin="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
```

Comment: This is what did it! I’m sorry I’m new to all of this, how can I tell the difference between a markup and a control with MahApps?

Comment: @AaronGDL Markup extensions derive from [`MarkupExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1). You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/PackIconUniconsExtension.cs) at GitHub and follow the inheritance chain, there you will find that `UniconsExtension` derives from `MarkupExtension` through `BasePackIconExtension`.

Comment: @AaronGDL Another option is to use the _Object Browser_ or _Go To Definition_ (F12) in Visual Studio to step through the base classes and there you will find the base class `MarkupExtension`, too. On the other hand, for `PackIconUnicons` you will find that it derives from `Control` if you follow the inheritance chain. There is also a [good documentation](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/wiki) available on GitHub.